# Mutation observer event new value

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I am learning to use the Mutation observer class, mostly here: https://javascript.info/mutation-observer

I know how to listen to changes of attributes, and how to get old attribute values using attributeOldValue. But can I get the new attribute value from the same event? If so, how? Thanks

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579682/mutationobserver-new-value-in-the-format-of-oldvalue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply query current value directly from the changed object.

```
// is element is an input
const newValue = document.getElementByID('myElement').value;


// or, if it is a any text element
const newValue = document.getElementByID('myElement').innerHTML;
```

Also, each `MutationRecord` have a property named `target` which contains all detailed information about changed object. So depending on `MutationRecord.type` (which tells us what type of the change have happened) you can get new value from corresponding property inside `MutationRecord.target`

Answer (score 0):

We can listen for mutations and take content from the target where it has already happened. (the example is not on your topic, but the principle is similar)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  let targetEl = document.querySelector('body');

  function checkChange(mutations, observer) {
     //****************************
     console.log(mutations[0].target.innerHTML);
     //****************************
  }

  let observer = new MutationObserver(checkChange);

  observer.observe(targetEl, {
     subtree: true,
     childList: true,
     characterData: true,
     characterDataOldValue: true,
  })
```

})

Comment: Code alignment is not okay.