# MutationObserver: new value in the format of `oldValue`

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I'm using a `MutationObserver` and I'd like to access the new value of the attibute. I try this:

```
newValue = mutation.target[mutation.attributeName]
```

However, if for example `mutation.attributeName == 'style'`, then `mutation.oldValue` and my `newValue` are formatted differently: `mutation.oldValue` is a string formatted like `newValue.cssText`, whereas `newValue` itself is a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object.

I would like to avoid programming for each possible `mutation.attributeName` things like "if `'style'`, use `.cssText`, if ..., use ...". There are too many possible attributes.

How do I get the new value in the format of `oldValue`?

---

Related questions don't answer my question:

- `mutation["addedNodes"][0]` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59179008/5231110) is undefined in my case.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58176006/5231110) requires the element to have an ID. That might be difficult to achieve in some cases.

Edit:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60593716/5231110) suggests `newValue = mutation.target.attributes.getNamedItem(mutation.attributeName)`, but that has a different format than `mutation.oldValue` as well. For details, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44328464/5231110).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes and properties are different things. To get the attribute string, you'd use `getAttribute`:

```
newValue = mutation.target.getAttribute(mutation.attributeName);
```

You were accessing the *property* from the element instance, which in the case of [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) is a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object reflecting the parsed style properties from the `style` attribute. While many attributes are reflected directly as properties (`id`, `name`), others are in a different form (like `style`) or aren't available as properties on the element at all.